# How do you a component whose constructor requires a parameter in a html file?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to AngularJs which I kind of find interesting. I want to create a component whose constructor takes a parameter of a string type. Now, when I declare the selector on HTML file, it does not render.

Here is the code:
component.ts file:

```
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit{  
 constructor(private param: string){}
 ngOnInit(){}
      }
```

component.html file:

When I use it like this on the HTML file, it complies but does not render the component

Comment: Can you show more code please? Your whole component and template could be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by generating a new service file by running 
    ng generate service service-name

This creates a service class that allows me to instatiate classes that depend on other classes.